# Restart Docker Container with new Image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

One of my Docker Containers can update itself (talking to the Docker Daemon using the Spotify Docker Client). After downloading the new image a container restart is required, with the new iamge of course.

If I just kill the running process inside the container, Docker restarts it using the old image. Is there any reliable way to force recreating the container using the new image? Couldn't find anything in the docker-compose docs. It's a single host environment only, no Kubernetes or something like that in use.

Compose file snippet:

```
  dockerctl:
    image: myimage
    container_name: dockerctl
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    ports:
      - "8099:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    restart: always
```

Comment: Docker stop followed by docker run?

Comment: It would help to know what your docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile look like. By default, the image has to be rebuilt. Depending on how you're addressing the base image, if the context hasn't changed `docker build` nor `docker-compose up` would detect a change.

Comment: The restart has to be initiated from within the running container. No command line. that would be too easy ;-)

Comment: docker build isn't involved, the new image is downloaded from registry.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of an old question, but this should do it: Update the image name in your docker-compose.yml and restart it by running `docker-compose up -d --no-deps dockerctl`.